# Collapse an element based on input from a REST call

Tags: reactjs

I have a REST service that return's a set of data. I would like to toggle some elements based on data from the service. But as you can see on this sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-gmqpp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The changes I do when toggle does no work. My best bet it is because media.toggle = !media.toggle; is not interpreted as a hook? How do I add a property to my data so I can use it in the render function for toggles etc? Or should I do it completely different?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CrawlJobs = () => {
  const [mediaList, setMediaList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMediaData = async () => {
      try {
        setMediaList([{ id: 1, name: "Facebook" }, { id: 2, name: "Twitter" }]);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchMediaData();
  }, []);

  const toggle = media => {
    media.toggle = !media.toggle;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {mediaList.map(media => (
        <div>
          <div onClick={() => toggle(media)}>Show</div>
          {media.toggle && <h1>Toggled context</h1>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrawlJobs;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `useState`, only updates utilizing the setter function (in your case, setMediaList) will toggle a rerender. Thus, within your toggle function, you will need to find the media item you want to toggle, update it, and save it using setMediaList.

For this, you need to be able to uniquely identify your media items. You can use `media.id` for that purpose.

```
{mediaList.map(media => (
  <div key={media.id}>
    <div onClick={() => toggle(media.id)}>Show</div>
    {media.toggle && <h1>Toggled context</h1>}
  </div>
))}
```

And your toggle function would look like this

```
const toggle = mediaId => {
    setMediaList(
      mediaList.map(media => {
        return media.id === mediaId
          ? { ...media, toggle: !media.toggle }
          : media;
      })
    );
  };
```

Here's an updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-qkvb7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Also note the react error in your console, the first jsx item in a `map()` function should have a uniquely identifiable `key` prop.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot  highly appreciated. When working Angular you can just edit your bound values. Is it normal to do it like this, or am I using the wrong approach. I always had the impression REACT was more easy that Angular. Seems kind of much work to do on the thwo way binding part? Could also just be a matter of getting use to it.

Comment: @ThomasSegato React has a steep learning curve compared to Angular, but it is worth it in my opinion. In this case I would recommend creating a smaller component that manages its own toggle, like in the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-nij8r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)